# Why am I getting no output from AND gates in Proteus?

Tags: logic-gates, proteus

[image: root sheet][image: Design in Proteus]

Given design works perfectly in actual.But in Proteus,there are no outputs from the AND gates pointed in the image attached.This happens when there is 'race condition' or undetermined signal.But I am unable to figure out what is the mistake in this design.[image: simulation log]
Root sheet(image attached)does not have U3.It is not clear why so.I did not manually change library or root sheet.Am I supposed to do such changes every such design so that I do not get this error?

Comment: Based on the error messages, there is something wrong with the library (a.k.a., "child sheet") underlying U3, the 74F08 quad 2-input AND gate. But there isn't enough information in the question to diagnose it any further than that.

Comment: @DaveTweed,I attached the root sheet image.It does not have U3.But I do not understand why...

Comment: I think it's a lib related issue. Go to Pick Device window again, find 74F08 and select it. If it shows "No simulator model" in the preview image to the top-right then you should select another AND-gate IC.

Comment: @RohatKılıç this worked!But,I do not get the point why Proteus kept such components if they cannot be used for simulation.Is there any special use of such components?

Comment: @KhodkumbheAwaniRamdas Actually, Proteus keeps some of the non-simulator model parts so that they can be used for only schematic/PCB design rather than simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a state machine. If you don't initialize the states of the flip-flops, the simulator will treat their outputs as "unknown", and this will propagate through the rest of the gates.

In contrast, a real circuit will always be in a particular state, even if you can't predict what that state is.

To fix this, assert your reset signal briefly at the beginning of the simulation.

Comment: There is a reset signal to each flip-flop.At the start,I reset all the flipflops(outputs of all the flipflops are 0) and then deactivate the reset.Still,it shows same error.Had it been the issue,it would have reflected to other gates output as well since they also receive flip-flop output as their input.